# Offline search of books in Amazon Cloud Reader

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services

I want to search the contents of my books in [Amazon Read](https://read.amazon.com/).
The Kindle offline program does not support it in OSX.

**Is there any way to search your amazon books while offline?**

Comment: To those voting to close as off-topic, from best I can tell, the user wants an _off-line_ search solution, which would be computer-centric and on-topic (IMO).

Comment: Which "official" offline programs did you try?  Which OS are you using?